# Ant using Fileset in jar task and renaming files

Tags: ant, jar

I have the following piece of code:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}">
     <fileset dir="${basedir}/resources"/>
        <include name="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml"/>
        <include name="META-INF/persistence-prod.xml"/>
     </fileset>
     [...]
</jar>
```

The problem is that `persistence-prod.xm1` should be `persistence.xml` when placed in the jar.

I know I could create a working directory and layout my whole jar there, and then jar that up. I know I can copy that one file elsewhere and rename it while copying. If I had a whole bunch of files named `*-prod.xml` to be renamed `*.xml`, I can use a [file mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) inside the copy task. However, I want to be able to rename the file right in the `<jar>` task. I tried adding `<globmapper>` to the jar task, but I got the error message: `jar doesn't support the nested "globmapper" element.`

Any idea how this rename can take place while jaring the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, the minute I asked the question, I figure out the answer:

I can't put `<globmapper>` directly into a `<jar>` task, but I can include `<mappedresources>` into the `<jar>` task, and place my `<globmapper>` in there:

#### Wrong:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}">
     <fileset dir="${basedir}/resources"/>
          <include name="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml"/>
          <include name="META-INF/persistence-prod.xml"/>
     </fileset>
     <globmapper from="*-prod.xml" to="*.xml"/>
     [...]
</jar>
```

#### Right:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/resources"/>
         <include name="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/resources">
            <include name="META-INF/persistence-prod.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <globmapper from="*-prod.xml" to="*.xml"/>
    </mappedresources>
    [...]
</jar>
```

I guess this makes sense since it limits my file mapping to just the `<mappedresources>` and not to all `<fileset>` of the `<jar>` task.